# Select only the most imminent dated record from multiple records

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using MS_SQL

I have a query where I am trying to return only the NEXT event (based on today's date) from a list of future events - whereby there may be multiple future occurrences for the record (entity_name) in the database.

Here is my code so far:

```
select fut.event_id, ent.entity_name, evt.event_datetime_utc
from evt_v1.ce_events_coverage_future fut
left join evt_v1.ce_events evt
on evt.event_id=fut.event_id
left join edm_v1.edm_entity ent
on ent.factset_entity_id=fut.factset_entity_id
left join edm_v1.edm_security_entity_map map
on map.factset_entity_id=ent.factset_entity_id
left join evt_v1.ce_event_types typ
on typ.event_type=evt.event_type
left join evt_v1.ce_market_times mkt
on mkt.market_time=evt.market_time
left join evt_v1.ce_fiscal_periods fis
on fis.fiscal_period=evt.fiscal_period
where map.isin in
('US38259P5089',
'US0378331005')
and evt.event_type='ER'
and evt.event_datetime >=GetDate()
order by ent.entity_name asc, event_datetime asc
```

Which returns following results:

```
event_id    entity_name event_datetime_utc
4097237 APPLE INC   2014-04-22 00:00:00.000
4188165 APPLE INC   2014-07-22 00:00:00.000
4270116 APPLE INC   2014-10-20 00:00:00.000
4339538 APPLE INC   2015-01-20 00:00:00.000
4097141 GOOGLE INC  2014-04-16 00:00:00.000
4188066 GOOGLE INC  2014-07-17 00:00:00.000
4269906 GOOGLE INC  2014-10-16 00:00:00.000
4339013 GOOGLE INC  2015-01-22 00:00:00.000
```

All I want to return is the most imminent records for each entity_name:

```
4097237 APPLE INC   2014-04-22 00:00:00.000
4097141 GOOGLE INC  2014-04-16 00:00:00.000
```

I'm sure this is quite straightforward but I'm not sure if this is best approached by using DATE functions, or some sort of RANK function (or neither!)?

Thanks in advance for your help,
E.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I assume the query is unnecessarily complicated (with all the unneeded tables) because your real query really does use fields from them.

Comment: Sorry - new to this site. I use MS-SQL. I have removed a majority of fields that are being returned for display purposes. The joins are required for the overall query.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rank()` or `row_number()`:

```
with t as (<your query here>)
select event_id, entity_name, event_datetime_utc
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by entity_name
                                order by event_datetime_utc asc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you could use a subquery to find those values. This depends on the assumption that `evt_v1.ce_events.event_datetime` is not null. In addition, if the additional criteria on map.isin is required for determining "next", you can simply expand the subquery.

```
Select fut.event_id, ent.entity_name, evt.event_datetime_utc
From evt_v1.ce_events_coverage_future As fut
    Join evt_v1.ce_events As evt
        On evt.event_id = fut.event_id
    Join edm_v1.edm_entity As ent
        On ent.factset_entity_id = fut.factset_entity_id
    Join edm_v1.edm_security_entity_map As map
        On map.factset_entity_id = ent.factset_entity_id
    Left Join evt_v1.ce_event_types As typ
        On typ.event_type = evt.event_type
    Left Join evt_v1.ce_market_times As mkt
        On mkt.market_time = evt.market_time
    Left Join evt_v1.ce_fiscal_periods As fis
        On fis.fiscal_period = evt.fiscal_period
Where map.isin In( 'US38259P5089','US0378331005' )
    And evt.event_type = 'ER'
    And evt.event_datetime =    (
                                Select Min( evt1.event_datetime )
                                From evt_v1.ce_events_coverage_future As fut1
                                    Join evt_v1.ce_events As evt1
                                        On evt1.event_id = fut1.event_id
                                    Join edm_v1.edm_entity As ent1
                                        On ent1.factset_entity_id = fut1.factset_entity_id
                                Where ent1.entity_name = ent.entity_name
                                    And evt1.event_datetime >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                                )
Order By ent.entity_name Asc, evt.event_datetime Asc
```

Secondly, you have used Left Joins in a number of places where it will not make any difference. Specifically, you have a Left Join on `edm_v1.edm_security_entity_map` but in the Where clause you are requiring that `map.isin` have a value by virtue of your In function and thus have effectively converted this Left Join into an inner Join. The same is true of the `edm_v1.edm_security_entity_map` table.

Comment: Thanks Thomas - this is an interesting alternative view from the first answer (which I have got to work nicely). I'll have a look at this one as well. Cheers.